# Biconnected undirected graph where removing an edge breaks the biconnectivity

Tags: graph, graph-theory

Actually this is not strongly related with algorithm analysis but since I couldn't get a significant result from Google, I would like to get some opinion.

So, definition of *biconnected undirected graph* is a connected graph that is not broken into disconnected pieces by deleting any single vertex (from Wikipedia). But I have a vertex where **removing any edge** from it breaks the biconnectivity of the graph.

I am trying to prove such a graph can have at most 2n-3 edges (where n is the number of vertices).

But I can not imagine such a graph where removing any edge breaks the biconnectivity. I am very confused. Is there a specific name for this kind of undirected graphs where removing an edge breaks the biconnectivity?

Or is there anything that you can suggest me to read?

Answer (score 1):

Any graph that is a ring with >3 vertices fulfills this criteria.

Removing either of the blue edges below means that removing the red vertex creates disconnected pieces of the graph.

This graph is then no longer biconnected if any edge is removed, but depending on the edge removed a different vertex will break the connectivity when it is removed.

[image]

Having thought about it more, any graph like this will also satisfy the criteria:

[image]

As removing any edge will leave the graph connected, but if then either the top or the bottom vertex (depending on the edge removed) is removed, the graph will no longer be connected.

A graph in this format has (n-2)*2 edges - so 2n-4 which is a lot closer to the limit you're looking for.